# Attaching CSS to block doesn't work

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

mymodule is in modules/custom directory.

```
$block['content']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module',
                                          'mymodule' . '/mymodule.css');
```

mymodule.css exists.

However file is not attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in your statement. It should be:

```
$block['content']['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.css';
```

Also, be sure to clear the cache after you add statements like this to your code.